# Calculate Weekend date

Tags: validation-rule

I have a scenario wherein, there is a field "A" which takes "Date" value. Field "B" should display the Weekend date based on field value "A". Like if "A" = 21-Thursday. Field "B" should display date "23rd" as it is the weekend of specified date. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: Doesn't include your exact requirement but worth knowing about: [USEFUL FORMULA FIELDS](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_useful_formula_fields.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
CASE( 
MOD(field A- DATE(1900, 1, 6),7), 
0, field A + 7, 
1, field A + 6, 
2, field A + 5, 
3, field A + 4, 
4, field A + 3, 
5, field A + 2, 
6, field A + 1, 
NULL 
)
```

Note that if a record is created on a Saturday, this will calculate the following Saturday. If you'd like to change that and return the same date you can just remove the '+7' from the first statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. A little more help pls. What if there is a field "A" which takes "Date" value. Field "B" should display the Weekend date based on field value "A". Like if "A" = 21-Monday-2015. Field "B" should display date 27-Sunday-2015 as it is the weekend of specified date.

Comment: you mean u need days in characters? like you mentioned "Monday" or "Sunday"?.

Answer (score 0):

Apex Date methods have a function called [ToStartOfWeek](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_toStartOfWeek) which returns start of the week depending on the users locale. Once you have that, it should be easy to get the weekend date.

> Date weekStart = myDate.toStartofWeek();